# How to reload items collection from webservice using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

`RadDropDownList` control binded to webservice. On loading control populated ok. But I need to update list of items, after modal window was closed.
Javascript function used to update list of items:

```
function Templates_RequestData(){
     var dropdown = $find("<%= Me.RadDropDownTemplates.ClientID%>");
     javascript: console.log(dropdown.get_items());  //works ok
     //dropdown.requestItems("", false); - undefined is not a function
     //dropdown.reload(); - undefined is not a function
     //dropdown.clearItems(); - undefined is not a function
     javascript: console.log("reload");
  }
```

RadDropDownList control

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownTemplates" runat="server"
    Skin="MetroTouch" Width="100%" DropDownWidth="200px" 
    AutoPostBack="false" 
    DefaultMessage=" - select template - "
    OnClientItemsRequesting="Templates_OnItemRequesting"
    SelectedValue='<%# Me.LastUsedTemplateID%>' >
    <WebServiceSettings Path="WebServices/Templates.asmx"
                        Method="GetAll"/>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

All methods i tried cause error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

`javascript: console.log(dropdown)` - return valid object of type RadDropDownList. Documentation from Telerik doesn't contain any function for updating items with webservice.
How I can update `raddropdownlist` from client code?

Comment: requestItems() method is usually used when you have Load On Demand, which was the case with RadComboBox. RadDropDownList does not have Load on Demand, so you probably need to use another method. Better ask the telerik support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because I need to update list of `RadDropDownList` only on the load of page and after modal window closed. I decide to make it manually.

I create a javascript function which call webservice and from result of webservice create DropDownListItems and add them to my list.
Then call this function in the `OnClientLoad` eventhandler of my `RadDropDownList` and in the in `OnClientClose` eventhandler of `RadWindow`